# xcode open tableview from nested views

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, nested

I've built an app that populates a tableview with numerous items. You can click on an item and it will open a detailed view of that item. You can then click a button that opens another view that shows specifics for the detailed item. I also have a few more nested views that are shown until you get to a completion view. I want a button click to pop me straight back to the tableview but haven't found a way. I've tried the following ideas:

1st (which will only dismiss to the previous screen):
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

2nd (doesn't work at all): 
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

3rd (doesn't do anything): 
WorkOrderTableViewController *pushTable = [[WorkOrderTableViewController alloc] init];
[UINavigationController pushViewController:pushTable animated:YES];

4th (doesn't do anything):
WorkOrderTableViewController *pushTable = [[WorkOrderTableViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pushTable animated:YES];

I've even tried calling the segues from previous screens/views. Also tried a class within a previous view controller.

Is there a way to jump right back to the table view? If so, how?

Comment: What about `popToViewController:animated:`?

Comment: I tried: 
WorkOrderTableViewController *pushTable = [[WorkOrderTableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:pushTable animated:YES];

But it did nothing as well.

Here is some more explanation as it maybe my lousy coding skills. Once in the detail view of the table item, you click a button that pushes to a service screen which has info to be put in. There is a continue button that pushes to the next screen where additional info can be put in. An additional button takes it to the final screen where I have the complete button. Help any?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the code in your above comment....

When you use `alloc` you're creating a **new** object.  What you want is to go back to an already existing view controller.  Save the original instance of `WorkOrderTableViewController` somewhere (app delegate?  custom parent controller?) so that you can return to it.

For example, you could:

Create a subclass of `UINavigationController` that responds to a notification by popping to the correct view controller.  (You need your own definition of what "correct" means.)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(popToTable) name:kReturnToTable object:nil];
}

- (void)popToTable {
    UIViewController *target = nil;
    for (UIViewController *controller in [self viewControllers]) {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]) {
            target = controller;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (target) {
        [self popToViewController:target animated:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error -- couldn't find my controller in %@", [self viewControllers]);
    }
}
```

Make the final controller's button post that notification.  (Notification name is defined in the last controller's header file.)

```
- (IBAction)backToTable:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kReturnToTable object:nil];
}
```